# UI grid - Print/Export Multiple grids into pdf on a single button click

Tags: angular-ui-grid, pdfmake

I am exploring the export to pdf feature. I have multiple grids in a page and want to be able to print all the data in grids in a button click. I am not finding any good documentation for this. Could any one either help me with how to approach or point to the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Search the ui-grid.js for pdfExport function. That is what is getting called from one grid if your grid includes enableGridMenu: true and you click Export (all || visible) data as pdf. Don't forget to include the uiGridExporter directive. So, on your button click (or whatever event) just call pdfExport for each of the grids that you want to create a pdf for.